# Reference for working knowledge of abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, reference-request

I am a graduate student in Economics, and I'm looking for a text which can give me a good working understanding of abstract algebra. I am specifically interested in those topics that are used in algebraic topology and lattice theory.

PS I do not have any background in abstract algebra, while I have a pretty good understanding of real analysis, general topology, and linear algebra (at the same level as an undergraduate degree in math).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is tough, because abstract algebra is very broad. I might recommend "A First Course in Abstract Algebra" by Fraleigh.

Comment: Looks pretty good,, thanks! It does talk about simplicial complexes like I wanted, and the chapter dependence schematic at the beginning of the book is quite helpful.